# How to solve the following Matrix problem when given the eigenvalue and eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have an unknown 2-by-2 matrix, A, which has an eigenvector of $\left(\begin{array}{cc}4\\-1  \end{array}\right)$ and eigenvalue of 4.

If $\left(\begin{array}{cc}x\\y  \end{array}\right)$ = $A^{4}$ $\left(\begin{array}{cc}4\\-1  \end{array}\right)$, I need to find the values of $x$ and $y$.

I'm not sure how to go about working backwards from the eigenvector and the eigenvalue. My attempt was to go from the eigenvector $\left(\begin{array}{cc}4\\-1  \end{array}\right)$ and get $x_1$ = 4 and $x_2$ = -1, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Hint: $AX=\lambda X$ where $X$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$

Comment: Follow the definition of eigenvalue. In your case $A(4,1)^T=4(4,1)^T$.

Comment: @Oolongmilktea Should that be -1 in those brackets?

Comment: Yes, a typo. I think you should just follow the definition and take the eigenvalue out for four times.

Comment: Indeed the whole point of eigenvectors is that the action of $A$ on them is particularly simple.